# How to parse JSON array of objects, and then append to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, parsing

Jupyter Notebook. A Batch API call returns a JSON array of objects. Parsing requires for loops (weird). I need to append certain JSON object info into a Pandas DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import requests
from scipy import stats
from pandas_datareader import data
import math
import json

symbol = 'AAPL'
# api_url = f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios-ttm/{symbol}?apikey={blah}'
response = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios-ttm/{symbol}?apikey={blah}')
# data = requests.get(api_url).json()
data = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios-ttm/{symbol}?apikey={blah}').json()
# data = json.loads(response.text)
data
```

This outputs stock data for AAPL. An array of objects starting with:

[{'dividendYielTTM': 4, ...'peRatioTTM': 5, ... 'priceToBookRatioTTM': 6, ... 'priceToSalesRatioTTM': 7 ...}]

Those values are fake, obviously. Anyhoo, to parse and print that, I have to use a for loop. Weird. But my code works. Next, I made a Pandas Dataframe. I just want to parse the object information from the JSON array, and append it. The name of the dataframe that I built is final_dataframe.

```
my_columns = [ 'Ticker', 'Price', 'Market Capitalization', 'PE_ttm', 'PE_%', 'PB_ttm', 'PB_%', 'PS_ttm', 'PS_%', 'EV/GP', 'EV/GP_%', 'EV/EBITDA', 'EV/EBITDA_%', 'RV']
final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = my_columns)
final_dataframe
```

My attempt to parse and append uses a for loop. My for loop is working (that is, it isn't giving me errors). But the Dataframe isn't appending the parsed info.

```
for i in data:
    final_dataframe.append(
        pd.Series(
            [
                symbol,
                'N/A',
                'N/A',
                i['peRatioTTM'],
                'N/A',
                i['priceToBookRatioTTM'],
                'N/A',
                i['priceToSalesRatioTTM'],
                'N/A',
                'N/A',
                'N/A',
                'N/A',
                'N/A',
                'N/A',
            ],
        index = my_columns),
        ignore_index=True
    )
final_dataframe
```

Please help. Anyone. I'll provide beer and pizza. I'm certain I have all the Python / Pandas / Numpy packages installed and updated.

Comment: Declare a list before loop, append those looped dataframes into a list and then use `pd.concat(that_list)` after loop ends.

Comment: "Append rows of other to the end of caller, returning a new object." -- [pandas.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append). See answer below by @crayxt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to use a for loop to populate your dataframe. You can load the data directly with `pd.read_json`. Eg. with some demo data:

```
import pandas as pd

symbol = 'AAPL'
blah = 'demo'
df = pd.read_json(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios-ttm/{symbol}?apikey={blah}')
df['symbol'] = symbol #create symbol column
```

You can now create the final dataframe and load the needed columns from `df`:

```
my_columns = [ 'Ticker', 'Price', 'Market Capitalization', 'PE_ttm', 'PE_%', 'PB_ttm', 'PB_%', 'PS_ttm', 'PS_%', 'EV/GP', 'EV/GP_%', 'EV/EBITDA', 'EV/EBITDA_%', 'RV']
final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = my_columns)
final_dataframe[['Ticker', 'PE_ttm', 'PB_ttm', 'PS_ttm']] = df[['symbol', 'peRatioTTM', 'priceToBookRatioTTM', 'priceToSalesRatioTTM']]
```

This will output:

|  | Ticker | Price | Market Capitalization | PE_ttm | PE_% | PB_ttm | PB_% | PS_ttm | PS_% | EV/GP | EV/GP_% | EV/EBITDA | EV/EBITDA_% | RV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAPL | nan | nan | 27.4713 | nan | 30.3039 | nan | 6.4423 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the result of append, e.g.

```
final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(...)
```